# ¿por qué no se agrega el PDFreader de Adobe en un form?

Tags: c#, windows-forms, pdf

Buen día compañeros. :)

Eh estado haciendo una app que haga PDF´s hasta ahí todo bien. solo que tengo un error al querer mostrarlo dentro de la misma ventana. el problema es que no me sale la herramienta para visualizar dichos PDF en la misma ventana, instale Adobe para leer los PDF ... y seguí los siguientes pasos.

1- en el cuadro de herramientas doy clic derecho y elegir elementos

2- me voy a la pestaña de Componentes COM

3- Selecciono los componentes de Adobe para los PDF y le doy en Aceptar

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

al darle clic en aceptar no marca ningún error, pero tampoco agrega nada.
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

ustedes que tienen más experiencia.

¿me pueden ayudar?

cualquier ayuda será bien recibida. :)

Por favor y muchas gracias.

Answer (score 0):

la respuesta es. por que aunque cree una aplicación de windows form, no la cree de la manera correcta puesto que debí haber creado una app, de tipo

Windows Forms (.Net Framework)

ese es el por que no sale.

:)